# Calling dplyr::count on multiple columns and return result in long format tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, purrr

Basically I want to do this, but keep the correct sorting order:

```
iris %>% 
    gather() %>% 
    group_by(key) %>% 
    count(value)
```

But gather drops attributes so the sorting information is lost.

(By sorting i mean that counts of each Species should be in the order of the factor levels, and the counts of each number should be numerical order).

Therefore I figured I had to nest all the columns, before i call gather, so that each columns becomes a list with one (dataframe) element.
Something like this, but it does not work:

```
iris %>% 
    summarise_all( function(x) nest(x)) %>% 
    gather() %>% 
    mutate( count_tibbles = map(data, key, function(x) x %>% count(key)))
```

Any ideas?

*Per request I have added an example of the desired output:*

```
first_column_count   = iris %>% count(value = Sepal.Length)   %>%  mutate( column_name = "Sepal.Length")  
second_column_count  = iris %>% count(value = Sepal.Width )   %>%  mutate( column_name = "Sepal.Width" )  
third_column_count   = iris %>% count(value = Petal.Length)   %>%  mutate( column_name = "Petal.Length")  
fourth_column_count  = iris %>% count(value = Petal.Width )   %>%  mutate( column_name = "Petal.Width" ) 
fifth_column_count   = iris %>% count(value = Species     )   %>%  mutate( column_name = "Species"     )


rbind(first_column_count, second_column_count, third_column_count, fourth_column_count, fifth_column_count) %>%
    select(3,2,1)
```

Incidentally, this is very close my first attempt:

```
iris %>% 
    gather() %>% 
    group_by(key) %>% 
    count(value)
```

But this is only because the factors levels in iris$Species are actually alphabetically sorted. I am looking for a solution which which does not sort alphabetically, which my first attempt does, but sorts factor variables according according to their factor levels, and numeric variables according to their numeric value (not their alphabetical value). So that it would also work in cases where the factor levels are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: Hey Rasmus, isn't `add_count()` is your desired function?

Comment: Thanks, maybe it is! How could I use ```add_count()``` in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude `Species` form `gather()` but include it in `group_by()` you can save Species sorting.

```
iris %>% 
  gather(key='key', value = 'value', 1:4) %>% 
  group_by(Species, key) %>% 
  count(value)
```

If you add factor to key, you can keep order of variables

```
iris %>% 
  gather(key='key', value = 'value', 1:4) %>% 
  mutate(key=factor(key, levels = names(iris[,1:4]))) %>% 
  group_by(Species, key) %>% 
  count(value)
```

So output looks like

```
# A tibble: 175 x 4
# Groups:   Species, key [12]
   Species key          value     n
   <fct>   <fct>        <dbl> <int>
 1 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.3     1
 2 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.4     3
 3 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.5     1
 4 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.6     4
 5 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.7     2
 6 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.8     5
 7 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.9     4
 8 setosa  Sepal.Length   5       8
 9 setosa  Sepal.Length   5.1     8
10 setosa  Sepal.Length   5.2     3
# ... with 165 more rows
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks. No, I would like the result to have the same structure as my first example, but with correct ordering. I would also like to avoid hard coding the names of variables in the code.

Comment: Updated with desired output.

Comment: You can try `pivot_longer()` instead of `gather()`.
It is not sorting alphabetically but in order of appearance from data.
So you can control sorting this way. 
See more about new function here https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html

Comment: Thanks, ```pivot_longer()``` looks promising. I will look into that :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize my question unclear because the the output from my example code was actually correct. However, my example code will not get the correct ordering in all cases. The code below will:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
iris %>% names() %>% 
   map( function(input_string) {
      var_name_from_input_string = rlang::sym(input_string)
      iris %>% count(category = !!var_name_from_input_string)  %>% mutate(category = as.character(category),
                                                                          var = input_string) %>% select(3,1,2)

   }
) %>% bind_rows()
```